# Title: JavaScript this behavior inside an arrow function used in Object.defineProperty

Tags: javascript, object, undefined, arrow-functions, defineproperty

Question:

I'm encountering unexpected behavior when using an arrow function as a getter in Object.defineProperty in JavaScript. Here's my code:

```
"use strict";

const obj = {
  a: 10,
};

Object.defineProperty(obj, "b", {
  get: () => {
    console.log(this.a, typeof this.a, this);
    return this.a + 10;
  },
});
```

When I try to access obj.b, the output is unexpected:

this.a is undefined
typeof this.a is 'undefined'
this refers to the global object (Window in a browser environment)
I expected this to refer to the obj object. Can someone explain why this behavior occurs and how to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: See the MDN page about this and note examples of getters/setters as functions: `Object.defineProperty(o, "b", {
  get() {
    return bValue;
  }, ...` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Answer (score 0):

> In arrow functions, this retains the value of the enclosing lexical context's this. In other words, when evaluating an arrow function's body, the language does not create a new this binding. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Since your arrow function is defined in the global scope, it's bound to `window`.

If you use a regular function, it's going to be bound to the object.